# javascript merge to array with name

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I am new in JS. It is a simple task but find it is hard to solve. I tried many methods including`concat`,`push`,`$.merge`
Here is an example

```
var a=[]
var b=[]
a["a"]="b"
a["c"]="d"
b["e"]="f"
b["g"]="h"
```

I want to get a result like [a:"b", c:"d", e:"f", g:"h"],
Here is some method I have tried

`a.concat(b)`get `[]`

`a.push(b)` get `1`

`$.merge(a,b)` get `[0:[e:"f", g:"h"],a:"b",c:"d"]`

I don't know where to go, Please help

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using arrays with named indexes rather than objects?

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem you're running into right now is that you are trying to use an array as an object, so first when you're initializing `a` and `b` you should use curly braces instead. And then to merge them, you can use the spread operator: `...`.

All of that culminates into this:

```js
let a = {};
let b = {};
a["a"]="b"
a["c"]="d"
b["e"]="f"
b["g"]="h"

a = {...a, ...b}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant get an array with key-value pairs its an invalid syntax, but you can create an object. Just spread both of your objects into an single object:

```js
var a=[]
var b=[]
a["a"]="b"
a["c"]="d"
b["e"]="f"
b["g"]="h"

let result = {...a,...b};

console.log(result);
```